# Second row data is NULL, needs to stop showing related Text in a PHP loop

Tags: php, loops, null

In my DB (column stageNum):
id#1 = 1
id#2 = NULL

In my PHP page:

// Query for Stage Numbers

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stage");
$row= mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

// Loop

```
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $i=0;
    $storeMyData = array();
    while($i < $num)
        {
        if(isset($row['stageNum'])){$stageNum= "STAGE " . mysql_result($query,$i,"stageNum") . "<br>";} else{$stageNum= NULL;}

            $storeMyData[] = $stageNum;  // store current data in array
            $i++;
        }
    /* this will echo your storedData of loop */
    foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)

    /* or join the data using string concatenation */
    $allFinalData2 = "";
    /* this will echo your storedData of loop */
    foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
        {
            $allFinalData2 = $allFinalData2.$prevData ;  // keep on concatenating
        }
    if(isset($allFinalData2)){echo $allFinalData2;}
```

My Final Output shows:

Stage 1

Stage

My Problems is:
I Don't want to show the second row "Stage" if the data is NULL.
How do I stop it from showing?

Answer (score 1):

try to use [is_null()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing your SQL query to not include `NULL` stages:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stage WHERE stageNum IS NOT NULL");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen($row['stageNum'])!=0)
{
echo "Stage".$row['stageNum'];
}
```

Comment: it's not quite correct. the string can be just empty but not null

Comment: I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_len()

Comment: oops, nevermind. I research "str_len", it's supposed to be "strlen". Tried it and it worked!

Comment: This solution works but why retrieve the records from the database if you don't need them? Wouldn't be better to change the query instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!is_null($prevData)) { //do your stuff here}
```

foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
        {

```
         if(!is_null($prevData)) {$allFinalData2 = $allFinalData2.$prevData ;  }
    }
if(isset($allFinalData2)){echo $allFinalData2;}
```

Comment: where do i specifically put this?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this -

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stage");
$storeMyData = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{
    if( !empty($row['stageNum']) )
    {
        $stageNum= "STAGE " . $row["stageNum"] . "<br>";
        $storeMyData[] = $stageNum;
    } 
}
```